# configure, make, git on windows = how to compile&install on windows

Tags: windows, installation, makefile

I want to make work [**ffmpeg-ruby**](http://github.com/gwik/ffmpeg-ruby) on **windows**. If possible. But I do not know how to do

- **configure**
- **make**

  `./configure --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-gpl`

  `make`

  `sudo make install`
- **git** on windows?

  `git clone git://github.com/gwik/ffmpeg-ruby.git`

  `cd ffmpeg-ruby`

  `gem build ./ffmpeg-ruby.gemspec`

  `sudo gem install ./ffmpeg-ruby-0.1.0.gem -- --with-ffmpeg-dir=/opt/ffmpeg`

-- sorry for the formatting, cannot make it look better

Comment: check out msys. Stands for minimal system. It includes windows ports of stuff like that. There is also CMake, you can write your own build script if there isn't alread one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've never used git before, you can use TortoiseGit as a GUI interface. This requires you have msysgit installed as linked by Ignacio. Might be nicer to get the sources.

You then launch the msys command line from windows having installed both Msys and MinGW. Navigate to your folder (you may want to mount them - see the fstab file in the etc directory of msys). There you can run ./configure and make.

make install is pretty meaningless on windows and sudo doesn't exist in msys, so skip that step - your binaries will be build in the source code folder.

Comment: could anybody tell me what I need to download and install? Out of MinGW and msys? I guess I do not need all the files to download...

Comment: No you don't, thankfully... you'll want gcc, g++, probably binutils, w32api. It looks like there's a mingw automated installer that should do it though!  Msys will come with make so just get the installer for windows. Likewise just get the installer for msysgit